# Listen for hover in legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to change the fill opacity of the dots in my scatter plot when the user hovers over the legend. I am attempting to mimic the block below:

http://blockbuilder.org/curran/0d2cc6698cad72a48027b8de0ebb417d

My code is available at:
http://bl.ocks.org/adamfknapp/c5cd902b20ea87b35e420f26f016e8f5/d52a30195fa709289a195cb6e9dbf0e8d23a3650

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Look at your bl.ocks again, it has an error message for you in the console. Please, share a **working** code, so we just have to deal with the hover issue.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mimic that effect comparing the datum of the legend with the data of the circles:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    g.selectAll("circle").style("opacity", function(e) {
        return e.result === d ? 1 : 0.1
    })
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    g.selectAll("circle").style("opacity", 1)
});
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/b44dc5aed8cec38660ca81662c2d6902/fd51ffdf111fa9487dd13bcae36189c7da97bd6c